# Enable Mongo Authentication using docker-compose

Tags: mongodb, authentication, docker, docker-compose

How can I enable authentication using `docker-compose` and `MongoDB`?
Here is my `docker-compose.yml`

```
version: "2"

services:
  mongo-db:
    image: "mongo:3.6.0"
    container_name: mongo-db
    ports:
      - 27017:27017
    environment:
      - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME=backend
      - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD=123456
      - MONGO_INITDB_DATABASE=backend
    command: mongod --bind_ip 0.0.0.0

  backend:
    build:
      context: .
    container_name: backend
    ports:
      - 3030-3039:3030-3039
    depends_on:
      - mongo-db
```

It works well when I'm not using authentication.

But when I enable authentication an error occurs:

```
mongo-db        | 2018-01-18T14:52:36.836+0000 I NETWORK  [conn4] received client metadata from 172.27.0.3:49742 conn: { driver: { name: "nodejs", version: "2.2.34" }, os: { type: "Linux", name: "linux", architecture: "x64", version: "4.4.0-109-generic" }, platform: "Node.js v9.3.0, LE, mongodb-core: 2.1.18" }
mongo-db        | 2018-01-18T14:52:36.866+0000 I ACCESS   [conn4] SCRAM-SHA-1 authentication failed for backend on backend from client 172.27.0.3:49742 ; UserNotFound: Could not find user backend@backend
```

There is a lot of solutions here on StackOverflow, and on the internet, but none of then works. Is there some changes on this image? Can I do that without building my own image?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[I had build a new image from mongo](https://hub.docker.com/r/vepo/mongo/) where I configure the database and user/password.

Now we can configure using:

```
services:
  mongo-db:
    image: vepo/mongo
    container_name: mongo-db
    ports:
      - 27017:27017
    environment:
      - AUTH=yes
      - ADMIN_USER=admin
      - ADMIN_PASS=admin
      - APPLICATION_DATABASE=backend
      - APPLICATION_USER=backend
      - APPLICATION_PASS=XXXXXXXXXXX
```